# Multilevel Marginal Structural Models and Centering Predictors

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, causality

I have read that centering the values of predictors (subtracting the individual, $i$, value from the group mean, $j$, value or the grand mean) in a multilevel models aids in the interpretability of multilevel modeling output.

Oftentimes, a motivator of adopting a multilevel model is the presence of panel data, with repeated observations of units over time. While a multilevel model can address certain features of panel data (nested structure with individual observations nested within units), MLMs alone do not account for the biasing properties of time.

I have been researching marginal structural models (MSMs) for some time, and I am fascinated with their application as they can address feedback loops ($X_{it-1} \rightarrow Y_{it-1} \rightarrow X_{it} \rightarrow Y_{it} \rightarrow X_{it+1}$ etc.) that theoretically exist within panel data. Naturally, this leads me to question how one might combine multilevel modeling with marginal structural models (a multilevel marginal structural model?)

First, is such a combination possible? If so, my second question concerns the interpretability of multilevel MSM output. Again, many have argued that centering is necessary for interpretability. In MSMs, covariates are included in the weights applied (inverse probability of treatment given covariates) and are not directly included in the regression equation. Would this centering only apply for the single predictor present in the multilevel MSM (the treatment)? Or, should centered covariate values be used to develop the inverse propensity scores that are then used to weight observations? Furthermore, if I am interested in estimating a within-between random effects model, specified as:

$y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_{W}(x_{ij} - \bar{xj}) + \beta_{B}\bar{x_j} + (u_j + e_{ij})$

Would I also need to include the group-level average as a covariate in an MSM and/or include it in the weighting scheme somehow? This may be nonsensical, but I am struggling to understand how the math behind these two methods may work if combined.

Comment: This is an interesting question! I think that centering in multilevel models doesn't necessarily make interpretation easier. But in 2-level panel settings, group mean centering in MLMs makes level 1 coefficients equivalent to fixed effect coefficients, helping to deal with level 1 endogeneity. The issue you are getting at with MSMs seems to deal with sequential ignorability concerns, which I have not seen addressed in the multilevel modeling context. Have you looked at Yiquing Xu's work? https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3979613

Comment: @ErikRuzek I have not yet, but I will be checking this out!